# Como programar mobile com o Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Olá, sei que o Delphi XE4 cria aplicativos mobile para IOS, mas será que ele faz a mesma coisa para Android mobile? E se faz qual é o nome da ferramenta?

Comment: De uma olhada neste link -> https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/create-android-apps

Comment: Mas ai está falando do Delphi XE8, eu queria saber do XE4

Comment: Amigo acredito que somente a partir do Delphi XE5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível desenvolver para Android com Delphi XE4. Mas a partir do Delphi XE5 (out/2013) isso é possível.

A situação atual está na resposta de *@MeuChapeu*.

O nome do *"framework"* utilizado para desenvolvimento multiplataforma no Delphi é Firemonkey (FMX).

Veja também: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598579/how-to-create-android-apps-using-delphi

Answer (score 1):

> Não achei nada relacionado a Android e Delphi XE4, somente em versões superiores. Uma alternativa seria atualizar a ferramenta para uma versão mais recente.

### RAD Studio XE8

**Plataforma de aplicações conectadas para Windows e além**

O Embarcadero® RAD Studio XE8 é a solução completa de desenvolvimento de softwares para o rápido design, codificação e extensão de aplicações "conectadas" do Windows, Mac, iOS, Android e IoT. Construa soluções de força industrial e prontas para os negócios, incorporando múltiplas plataformas clientes nativas, extensões mobile, dispositivos inteligentes como relógios inteligentes e outros gadgets IoT, serviços nas nuvens, dados corporativos e embutidos. Remova o fator dificultador de múltiplas equipes e múltiplas bases de código e crie aplicações nativas rápidas para Windows, OS X e mobile a partir de uma única base de código.

Fonte: [Site Embarcadero](https://www.embarcadero.com/br/products/rad-studio)

### Visual Studio 2015 (Sugestão)

A Microsoft lançou o VS 2015 que está em RC(Release Candidate), ele possui a versão community para você usar gratuitamente.

Crie aplicativos para múltiplas plataformas para Windows, iOS, Android e muito mais usando um único IDE.

- Xamarin para o Visual Studio: um código comum base em c# para todos
  os dispositivos
- Apache Cordova com o Visual Studio: um código comum base para HTML,
  CSS e JavaScript ou Typescript
- Visual Studio Tools para o Unity: desenvolvimento de jogos 2D/3D em
  c#
- C++ para desenvolvimento de plataforma cruzada: compartilhado
  bibliotecas de código e aplicativos em C++

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com VS2015 é possível criar aplicativos para iOS, Android, Windows Phone. É possível também criar aplicativos Híbridos utilizando o apache cordova + html/css/JS.

Mais Informações no site do [VS2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/)